# Як правильно перекласти з російської "Советское шампанское"?

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, from-russian

Допоможіть перекласти з російської "Советское шампанское". Воно буде "советскоє", "совєтське" чи "радянське"?

Comment: До речі, цікаве запитання. Десь мають бути якісь більш-менш офіційні рекомендації щодо передачі іншомовних назв торгових марок (десь прямо на цьому сайті було про передачу іншомовних назв журналів, але це все-таки інше, і не можу знайти). Хоча якщо мається на увазі варіант, що виробляється в Україні, а не в Росії, то тут можуть бути свої спрощення при переданні (типу, паралельно з російською назвою на етикетці десь може бути визначено (навіть офіційно юридично) український варіант назви торгової марки).

Comment: Якби «Советское шампанское» було російською географічною назвою, то за [§ 109.1.в](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par109p1v) (бо від _сов**ѣ**тъ_, адже в однокорінних словах маємо _сов**і**т_, _прив**і**тання_, _зав**і**тати_ тощо) і [§ 109.7.а](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par109p7a) «Правопису» 2015 було б «Сов**є**т**ське** шампан**ське**», але це торгова марка, а не географічна назва.

Answer (score 8):

В загальній практиці не прийнято перекладати назву торгівельної марки на інші мови. 
Наприклад, російський "Сбербанк" в Україні діє під назвою "Сбербанк", а не "Сбєрбанк" - [офіційна сторінка](https://ua.sberbank.ua/).
Так само й "Советское Шампанское" є зареєстрованою торгівельно маркою, тому перекладати її назву на українську мову не варто. Інша справа, що частина назви ("Советское") підпадає під дію закону "Про засудження комуністичного та націонал-соціалістичного (нацистського) тоталітарних режимів в Україні та заборону пропаганди їх символіки" і стала забороненою. Тому, "Київський завод шампанських вин "Столичний" [змінив назву торгівельної марки](http://www.sekt.kiev.ua/ua/news/zmni-u-nazv-tm-sovetskoe-shampanskoe) з "Советское Шампанское" на "Советовское Шампанское".

Comment: Re: *є зареєстрованою торгівельно маркою* — Це не так: московський совок незаконно користувався цією назвою. Насправді, саме існування назви «Совєцкоє шампанскоє» є незаконним, оскільки, відповідно до міжнародного торговельного та ринкового права, вино, вироблене з винограду, вирощеного **за межами французької провінції Шампань**, [не може](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B5)) називатися «шампанським».

Comment: Законне використання чи ні, сутті питання це не міняє. ТМ "Советское Шампанское" є зареєстрованою торговельною маркою на території України (що легко перевірити через онлайн-реєстри).

Comment: Ви написали «зареєстрованою». Ця ТМ не є і не може бути зареєстрованою. Ця помилка у вашій відповіді могла б бути просто юридичним казусом, але на ній ґрунтується значна частина відповіді «варто / не варто». Наголошую: уся відповідь ґрунтується на юридичних аргументах, а не на лінгвістичній логіці. Я згоден, що саме запитання — погане, непропрацьоване, primarily opinion-based і заслуговує закриття, але це не привід давати на нього непропрацьовані відповіді.

Comment: Ця ТМ є зареєстрованою. Ще раз кажу - перевірте реєстри ТМ на території України. Не треба казати на "Чорне" - "Біле". Помилки у відповіді намає. Було питання як перкласти, а не чи можна використовувати слово "Шампанское". Тому не заглиблюйтесь у юридичний аспект, він немає жодного відношення до суті питання. Лінгвічстична логіка проста - торгівельні марки не перекладаються. Крапка.

Comment: @bytebuster, Ви неправі, Ви змішуєте різні поняття. Є багато торгових марок зі словом _шампанське_ (зокрема «Радянське Шампанське Марінталь», «Советное Шампанское», «Советовское Шампанское», «Советоское Шампанское», «Советское Шампанское», «Шампанское Marengo»,  «Шампанское Нового года», «Шампанское Oreanda» тощо), зареєстрованих в Україні (а тж. ще ін., зареєстровані в РФ, і ще ті, які колись були існували в СРСР, але вже не існують). Можливо, вони зареєстровані з порушенням якихось норм і після постанови суду будуть скасовані, але наразі вони перебувають у реєстрі торгових марок.